# ERROR NG0900 when trying to retrieve contact info

Tags: angular, frontend

I'm currently developing my portfolio web application. I want to list all my contact info that i scrape from the web using jsoup. I did that correctly, and when i call the endpoint i see all my data in the browser, but when i call the same endpoint in angular i get NG0900 error.

NOTE: I did the exactly same thing when i list my projects, and they work flawlessly, but here I get that NG0900 error. Here is my code:

contact.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Contact } from 'app/common/contact';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ContactService {
  private contactURL: string = "http://localhost:8080/contact";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getContact(): Observable<Contact[]>{
    return this.http.get<Contact[]>(this.contactURL);
  }
}
```

contact.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Contact } from 'app/common/contact';
import { ContactService } from 'app/services/contact.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css']
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

  contact: Contact[] = [];

  constructor(private contactService: ContactService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.listContact();
  }

  listContact(){
    this.contactService.getContact().subscribe(data => 
      this.contact = data);
  }

}
```

contact.component.html

```
<section>
  <div class="contactTitle">
    <h2>Contact me!</h2>
    <p *ngFor="let tempContact of contact">
      {{ tempContact.firstName }}
      {{ tempContact.lastName }}
      {{ tempContact.phone_number }}
      {{ tempContact.dob }}
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Is it because when I retrieve the contact info, I receive only one element of an array?

Thank you all in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  listContact(){
    this.contactService.getContact()
        .subscribe(data => 
            this.contact = [data]); 
  }
```

received data is not iterable